# Using DocC for an Objective-C project

Tags: docc

I am working on an Objective-C library, that is also available via Swift Package Manager, namely [Sentry](https://swiftpackageindex.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa). We want to generate API docs using DocC, but I am running into the problem where when I generate the documentation I get this error:

```
error: target 'Sentry' is not a Swift source module
```

Weirdly enough when I build the documentation within Xcode itself (Product -> Build Documentation) it works perfectly well.

This is the command I am using on the command line to try to generate the docs:

```
swift package \
  generate-documentation \
  --allow-writing-to-directory ./docs \
  --target Sentry \
  --output-path ./docs \
  --transform-for-static-hosting \
  --hosting-base-path Sentry
```

And our Package.swift can be found [here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa/blob/master/Package.swift).

So why is it that Xcode can generate the docs perfectly fine, but I can't do it using `swift-docc-plugin`?